# need to print current row position number in block for most popular article

Tags: theming

I created a view mode named "small-sidebar" and here I need to print current row position number in this block...

I'm using this code :

```
    <article class="large-sidebar-article">
      <div class="article-image">
        <?php echo $content['small_image']; ?>
      <div class="label-no">
        <?php echo $label; ?>
      </div>
    <div class="article-title">
      <?php echo $content['title']; ?>
       <span>
        <?php  echo $content['read_more_link']; ?>
       </span>
    </div>
    <?php render($node); ?>
    </article>
```

but it not show the current position

in the div class `lebel-no` I need to print the current position

Comment: what is your mean `current row position` ?

Comment: means views-row position

Comment: can u get a screenshot of your views and put here?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two steps below,

**STEP : 1**

Add the views result counter under the fields option
Ex:
**Fields**
Global: View result counter
Content: Title
Content: Body

[image: Screen shot on adding a View result counter]

**STEP : 2**

If you want to theme it in your own way add the following tpl.php file in your theme folder,

views-view-field--custom-view-theming--counter.tpl.php

I have added the following html to theme it like a tab

```
<span style="margin-bottom: 20px;padding: 5px;border-radius: 3px;background: #479ED2;color:#fff;">
    View result counter:<?php print $output; ?>
</span>
```

Thats all about bringing a view counter in your block.

[image: Screen shot on bringing views counter variable in block]